# Image source not changing

Tags: javascript

I have an image and a button, what I'd like to happen is that when the button is clicked the source to the image is changed to another one. Whenever I click the button nothing is happening.

My code for the image is

```
<img id="chestImg" border="0" src="img/chestClosed.png" alt="Chest!">
```

And my code for the button is

```
<button id="openChest" onclick='changeImage("chestImg","img/chest.gif");' > Open Chest! </button>
```

My **changeImage** function looks like this

```
function changeImage(obj,img) {
  obj.src = img;
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, you'll have more of this elements or only one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj` can't be a string like you have it because that string isn't a DOM image object and thus doesn't have the `.src` property you want.

You could change the code to this:

```
function changeImage(id, url) {
   document.getElementById(id).src = url;
}
```

which is then called like you have it:

```
changeImage("chestImg", "img/chest.gif")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JS function is incorrect, you are passing a string "element id" and using it as an DOM element, which it isn't.

So your function should be like something:

```
document.getElementById("[element id]").src = [new value];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `("[element id]").src = [new value];` might be quite confusing for people learning JS. Use dummy *realAlike* values instead, like i.e: `("elementId").src = someNewValue;` or be more creative than me. Any way the user uses some arguments that you did not matched at all.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try to be more precise. 

But my answer was to point him to the correct solution.

Also the convention I used is of a more general solution not specific to the problem and I wasn't intending to do that.

Comment: I like your way really much, but you would not believe with what kind of issues people are fighting here ;)

Comment: You removed my score for no reason, my answer wasn't incorrect. Thanks for that also

Comment: i'm sorry, what score? I did not removed anything... Not sure I'm following this conversation

Comment: totally agree with you. will be careful next time.

Cheers :)

Comment: No worries, earlier the question poster voted my answer as useful but I thought you removed it as you had commented instead seems the poster might have ...
no worries enjoy and cheers :)

Comment: Dunno really, noone can remove other peoples votes, and who voted it's not public. Neither the admins knows it. We can only vote, delete, edit questions/answers. Take a look how jfriend00 answered the question, sometimes people like to just copy-paste your answer and be amazed... instead of thinking what's the `[]` you used, an array or just an pseudo-code.... :) hope you got my thoughts! Happy coding and hope to see you around!

Comment: Yes I get your point, I have just started being active (answering), so your guidance and feedback is important.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    function changeImage(obj,img) {
       obj.src = img;
    }
```

the "obj" is not object,think about it."obj.src" is not attribute of the object .
so,you should get the object first:

```
var object = document.getElementById("chestImg").
```

then:

```
object.src=[value];
```

Answer (score 0):

In changeImage function your parameter is not an object. So try this:

```
<img id="chestImg" border="0" src="img/chestClosed.png" alt="Chest!">
<button id="openChest" onclick='changeImage("chestImg","img/chest.gif");' > Open Chest! </button>

function changeImage(id,img) {
  var obj = document.getElementById(id);
  obj.src = img;
}
```